# How to use symbols in if statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make simple if statement to to compare if user have have typed: "+" symbol. Can't get it to work for some reason. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried? Including your code in the question makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: If user typed the "+" symbol where? In a text box, in a console? Be more specific. Also, provide your code. What have you tried already? And read on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: string operator = Console.ReadLine(); if (operator.Equals("+")){}

Comment: you cannot name a variable `operator` - it has a special meaning in C#

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
operatorStr=Console.Readline();
if(operatorStr.Contains("+"))
{
    \\do something
}
```

which will 'do something' if the user has included the `+` symbol anywhere in thier input.

Alternatively:

```
if(operatorStr=="+")
{
    \\do something
}
```

to 'do something' if they keyed '+' exactly

[UPDATE] Having originally typed this using the original variable name of `operator` I just realised this is (of course!) a C# reserved keyword - this is perhaps the source of the problem.

Comment: actually - if Im going to be self-critical `operatorStr` is a pretty duff name for the variable but using good names are surely outside the scope of the answer to this question